# set static ip problem

Tags: networking, network-manager, static-ip

I've tried to set this right for some hours, but when I restart service networking, I don't have any ip address at all. My `/etc/network/interfaces` look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.5
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

I have also edited my NetworkManager.conf like this:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

I have checked that the ip adress 192.168.1.5 is not used on other machines. Have anybody a clue what is wrong with my setup?

Comment: "auto eth0"     before iface?

Comment: try "ifup eth0" ... if no ip is assigned yet. ... otherwise "ifdown eth0; ifup eth0"

Comment: The eth0 stanza should begin with auto if you want it to start whenever your network service starts. With your current set up it looks like `ifup eth0` will bring it online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not `auto lo`, because it is `auto eth0`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address ...
netmask ...
gateway ...
```

You can check Ethernet Interface with = command : `ifconfig -a`

Comment: Like this? auto, lo iface lo inet loopback, auto eth0 etc

Comment: I don't know if I'm a little slow, but this is a litle confusing. I think you must write all the lines in the same form as in your answer. Can you do that?

Comment: I've got it now. I didn't run ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0 as root. I also didn't recognize this command to be run after I had edited the interface file. I works nx.